# Question on why some answers to an onhold question deleted, others not?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Question [My wife and I just had a big blow-up](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/16514/my-wife-and-i-just-had-a-big-blow-up-and-i-hardly-understand-it) was put on hold because it was considered unclear.  I have been through a similar situation and had posted an answer.  There's a comment from sphennings that since the question isn't clear, it's impossible to judge if my answer is useful.  I assume that's why my answer was deleted.

I'm curious as to why the other answer to the question wasn't deleted.  Seems like the same logic would apply?

As a side note, I've been through the experience that the OP had, and I do believe I understand his question, and that my answer applied.

Comment: And now I'm wondering why this is downvoted?  Is there a more appropriate place to ask this than Meta?

Comment: This is the place to ask for this. I'm on mobile for the weekend so I can't write an answer that does your question justice.

Comment: It looks like the entire question is now deleted by its owner, but that there were 3 answers to it that all got deleted at some point before that. My best guess is that these posts were in the review queue at different times :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell thanks, I couldn't figure out what was going on.  That makes sense.